# Java file record's intersection

Tags: java

I have two files `employee.txt` and `salary.txt`. `employee.txt` contains records of employee details like ( `empId, empName , age` ) as CSV and `salary.txt` contains (`empId,salary,TDS paid, ...`).

I want to write the common records of both the files  (based on `empId` being equal) in a third file. I want intersection of the records like a `JOIN` operation in database.

How can I efficiently do this using Java (like using some Collection ).

Comment: Are you limited to java, or are other tools open to you? You can certainly achieve this in java, but I think it could be done much more efficiently in other languages.

Comment: Sorry,I want only a Java solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run over the first file and maintain a hashtable where the key is the empid and value the values from employee.txt. Then in the next step you run over the second file. Using the empid from the second file lookup in the built hashtable whether you have such a key. If yes: get the value from the hashtable and write it along the record info from the second file. No: just skip the record. Repeat until the end of the second file.

Comment: Thanx bro, I think this the solution I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way could be loading the contents of your two files into a database system of your choice. Do a SQL JOIN on the resulting two tables and write the result to another csv file. That could probaly even be done without Java at all. Simly using a DBMS Management Tool like phpMyAdmin for Mysql.

The other way would be to read in both files, either writing your own csv "Parser" or using some [existing one](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). Then in a double loop check both files for equality on empId and store the common records to a 3rd array. Which can be exported to csv, as before, either manually or with a csv class of your choice.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: In this case I have to check each record every time in the second file as the second file may or may not have the emplId present that was in the first file and also it can be present at any random row.

Comment: Well yes, it's not as efficient as it could be. But depending of the number of entries in the input files and the frequency with which this little join tool is used it might be a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since JOINs are what databases are all about and you'd basically implement a (partial) database yourself, why not just use one of the existing in-memory databases?

[HSQLDB](http://www.hsqldb.org/) is my personal favorite, but there' also [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (a.k.a [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html)).

HSQLDB can even use your [CSV files directly as tables](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch06.html)!